# PyCharm hitting MemoryError when doing conditional .loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, out-of-memory

I'm running this on a large csv file (6mm+).

- The script works fine for other analysis if I comment out the
  conditional .loc so it's not a file loading issue.
- If I use a smaller file the script works fine even with the
  conditional .loc so I don't think there's a code error.

For some reason it seems that the MemoryError comes about when applying a conditional .loc to a LARGE dataframe column.

Any help on how to overcome the MemoryError when using the conditional .loc would be greatly appreciated.

```
columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
EUR = pd.concat(
    (chunk for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, header=None, sep=";|,", engine="python", chunksize=100000)),
    ignore_index=True)

EUR.columns = columns

EUR['Date'] = EUR['Date'].str.cat(EUR['Time'], sep=" ")

EUR['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(EUR.Date, dayfirst=True)

del EUR['Time']
del EUR['Date']
rows = EUR.shape[0]
print('Rows: ' + str(rows))
EUR['Date-1'] = EUR['datetime'].shift(-1)  # creating a new column
EUR['Open-1'] = EUR['Open'].shift(-1)  # creating a new column
EUR['TimeDiff'] = EUR['Date-1'] - EUR['datetime']
EUR['Minutesdiff'] = EUR['TimeDiff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's') / 60
EUR['GapPercent'] = [
    (EUR.loc[ei, 'Open-1'] / EUR.loc[ei, 'Close'] - 1) * 100 if EUR.loc[ei, 'Minutesdiff'] > 44 else np.NaN for ei
    in
    EUR.index]

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(EUR['GapPercent'].max())
print(EUR['GapPercent'].min())
rslt_df_pos = EUR.loc[EUR['GapPercent'] >= 0.75]
rslt_df_neg = EUR.loc[EUR['GapPercent'] <= -0.75]
rslt_df_pos.to_csv(r'''C:\gap_exports\EURposgap.csv''', index=True, header=True)
rslt_df_neg.to_csv(r'''C:\gap_exports\EURposgap.csv''', index=True, header=True)
```

Here's the output error

Rows: 6525490

1.6992939815894115

-1.2157646236684472

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Gap_testing/$$$ backtestb.py", line 290, in 
load_csv(sheet)

File "C:/Gap_testing/$$$ backtestb.py", line 51, in load_csv
rslt_df_pos = EUR.loc[EUR['GapPercent'] >= 0.75]

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1768, in **getitem**
return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1914, in _getitem_axis
return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1784, in _getbool_axis
return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=axis)

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3409, in _take_with_is_copy
result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis, **kwargs)

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3392, in take
self._consolidate_inplace()

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5347, in _consolidate_inplace
self._protect_consolidate(f)

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5336, in _protect_consolidate
result = f()

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5345, in f
self._data = self._data.consolidate()

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 940, in consolidate
bm._consolidate_inplace()

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 945, in _consolidate_inplace
self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1887, in _consolidate
list(group_blocks), dtype=dtype, _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate

File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 3099, in _merge_blocks
new_values = np.vstack([b.values for b in blocks])

File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in vstack
File "C:\Gap_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 283, in vstack
return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)

File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in concatenate
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 348. MiB for an array with shape (7, 6525490) and data type float64

Comment: What exactly is written in the error? Could you put the entire error message? It might help in understanding it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I just added the output and error

Comment: upgrade your mem :) or try using [dask](https://dask.org/)

Comment: I see, this means that you are using a dataframe that's just too big, so you don't really have many options I guess, other than using dask as acushner said. The other thing might be to reduce the memory footprint of your dataframe, for example reducing the precision of some columns if you don't really need much precision, thus avoiding memory issues. Some ideas here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/

Comment: 348mb shouldn't be an issue. My machine has 16gb of RAM. 

The thing is that the dataframe runs fine up until the .loc. You can see it was able to load the dataframe and then return row count, max/min gap. That's why I don't think it's an issue with the loading of the dataframe but an issue with conditional .loc on such a large column. Hoping there's a better where to conditionally return rows or setup a tweak so that it doesn't error out.

Comment: I see your point, and indeed I'm only guessing here, but if you notice, in your code you are adding more and more columns to an already big DataFrame (considering your output of the number of rows) with high precision floats (float64). That's why I think it might just be an issue of memory, depending on maybe what other things you are running in that machine at the same time... Because the thing is that you are mentioning .loc, but issue could be lack of memory to temporarly store the return of "EUR['GapPercent'] >= 0.75" (which will be a Series, not just an array)

Comment: I would also keep track of how memory is being used in the system. This will allow you to see whether your memory is actually getting to limit, or maybe pycharm is itself having some sort of strange limit on the programs it runs

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to handle this but my solution was a while loop to break up the .loc into 400k slices.

```
column_cycle_open = 0
column_cycle = 400000
rslt_df = pd.DataFrame()

while column_cycle < rows:
    rslt_df = rslt_df.append(EUR[column_cycle_open:column_cycle].loc[EUR['GapPercent'] >= 0.75], ignore_index=True)
    rslt_df = rslt_df.append(EUR[column_cycle_open:column_cycle].loc[EUR['GapPercent'] <= -0.75], ignore_index=True)
    column_cycle_open += 400000
    column_cycle += 400000

rslt_df.to_csv(r'''C:\gap_exports\EURgap.csv''', index=True, header=True)
```

Happy to provide answer credit to a more elegant solution